# can we use toggle instead of the if/else and hide/show logic

Tags: javascript

I am looking to handle this without the use of if/else if/else and the hide/show . can we use toggle to  handle this scenario?

```
$("#target").change(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value === "A" || value === "B") {
        $ele1.show()
        $ele2.hide()
    } else if (value === "C") {
        $ele2.show()
        $ele1.hide()
    } else {
        $ele1.hide()
        $ele2.hide()
    }

});
```

Comment: Did you try with `.toggle()` ? See [Jquery toggle](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: This likely has nothing to do with `node.js`, since it has no browser instance, hence no jQuery (removed the tag).

Comment: toggle(true/false)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach :

```js
const toggleMap = {
 "A" : 1,
 "B" : 1,
 "C" : 2
},
$elements = $("element"); // cache all the elements you want to toggle

$("#target").change( elem => {
    $elements.hide(); // Hides all elements
    $elements[ toggleMap[elem.target.value] ].show(); // Shows only element 1/2/3 depending on value
});
```

Advantage : you can easily add, remove and control as many elements you want, simply by updating `toggleMap`.

Answer (score 0):

A way to deal with different scenario without using too many if/else is to create an object of functions:

```
var handler = {
    A: () => {
        $ele1.show();
        $ele2.hide();
    },
    B: () => {
        $ele1.show();
        $ele2.hide();
    },
    C: () => {
       $ele2.show();
       $ele1.hide();
    },
    default: () => {
        $ele1.hide();
        $ele2.hide();
    }
};

const handle = (value) => {
    const func = handler[value] || handler.default;
    func();
}

$("#target").change(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();    
    handle(value);
});
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is, if you have 10 elements to toggle and you click element 8, you will have to manually write `$ele1.hide(); $ele2.hide(); $ele3.hide(); $ele4.hide(); $ele5.hide(); $ele6.hide(); $ele7.hide(); $ele8.show(); $ele9.hide(); $ele10.hide(); `. ---> _10 times_ <--- . There are more elegant solutions, like using a class.

Comment: @JeremyThille My answer shows a way to avoid having to write many if/else disregarding the specific implementation because we don't know what is the context of the question. Maybe there are only two large elements on the page. If there were many, it would indeed be interesting to use an array